# Image resizing distorted in Safari on iOS

Tags: html, css, ios, safari, flexbox

My goal is to stretch an image proportionally according to the page width. I use the following HTML:

```
<div class="idv algn_c">
  <img src="image-path.png" draggable="false">
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.idv{
    display: flex;
}
.idv img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    user-select: none;
}
.algn_c{
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 1.5em auto;
}
```

This works really well on Chrome, FF, Edge and scales the image nicely (according to its aspect ratio):

[image]

But when I try it on my iPhone in Safari (iOS v.13.4.1) it gives me this distorted image:

[image]

What am I doing wrong there?

*EDIT: Just realized that I didn't mention that the document has the following meta-tag:*

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

@c00000fd first add this meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
                then you have to use **.idv {align-items: start;} .idv img{ width: 100%; }** then your image will not be stretch. Hope it help

Comment: Thanks. Actually adding `align-items: start;` to `.idv` fixes it for Safari. The question is why? Do I need that `align-items:` selector, was it my fault for not using it? Can you explain.

Comment: @c00000fd, you are using CSS flex so your all divs will get height 100% and will be stretch. that's **align-items** CSS proper is important for display flex. If you don't use this then you will face a problem. You can check this *https://autoprefixer.github.io/* for CSS prefix. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Find the width of your layout design, and specify the following in the stylesheet:

```css
body {
  min-width: (layout width)px;
}
```

If that doesn't work, add the following to your html section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

---

If this isn't the issue, try adding a container to the image wherein the image fits the size of that container, and call for the container beforehand with `<div>`. In the container, specify `align-items: flex-start` (also replaceable with `start` or `self-start`). Like so:

```css
.idv {
  display: flex;
}

.idv section:first-child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.idv img {
  width: 240px;
  /* Insert the actual width of your image here */
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="idv">
    <img src="image-path.png">
</div>
```

Switching out `align-items: flex-start;` with `flex-direction: column;` should work as well.

Comment: Thanks. I did have the `viewport` metatag originally. Forgot to mention it. Then tried your `min-width` suggestion and it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried adding a container to your CSS with an `align-items` property?

Comment: No. Sorry. I'm not sure I know what you're talking about.

Comment: You pretty much got it, actually. Updated my answer. If that doesn't work, try adding `flex-direction: column;` instead.

Comment: Same question as I asked the other guy. Adding `align-items: start;` to `.idv` fixes it for Safari. No need to do anything else. The question is, why do I need that `align-items`, is it just Safari thing?

Comment: Good to hear! `flex-start`, `self-start`, and `start` all essentially work the same way with minute differences. As far as I know it is just a Safari thing -- different browsers use different rendering engines so support isn't uniform across them. For example Safari also has a similar bug when `height:` is set to `100%` instead of `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the answer:

If you create something like this:

```
<div style='display:flex' class='idv'>
  <img src="something.jpg" width="x" height="x" />
</div>
```

The `.idv` div uses `align-items:stretch` by default.

To solve the distortion issue, just add `align-items:flex-start` or `align-items:center` in `.idv` and this distortion will be solved. Otherwise `height:auto` or any other `height:xx` become useless.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a padding problem: Setting `padding: 0` on the parent element showed the `100%`-sized image normally.